# Error: E2564 Could not find program, 'C:\bin\JarSigner.exe'

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to compile a simple empty form for Android. I installed lots and lots of stuff and have been fighting with the whole thing for hours.
Now it says:

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E2564 Could not find program, 'C:\bin\JarSigner.exe'
```

There is no directory C:\bin and JarSigner.exe is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

How can I specify correct path to it? Why are there so many problems with compilation for Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in RAD Studio's documentation:

[E2564 Could not find program, 'path'](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2564_Could_not_find_program,_%27path%27)

> You must ensure that the [Android SDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/SDK_Manager) that you have [assigned to the Android target platform in your project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Activating_and_Configuring_the_Target_Platform#To_configure_a_target_platform_for_your_project) is configured with the right **JarSigner location** path. You can review and edit your Android SDK properties from the [SDK Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/SDK_Manager#Android_SDK.2C_NDK_and_Java_Properties).

Comment: JarSigner only supports the `v1` signing scheme, ApkSigner is recommend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install jdk from https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8
2. Update SDK path Android: Project -> Target Platforms -> Android 32-bit or 64-bit / mouse popup "Edit SDK" / Java for KeyTool and Jarsinger
   [image]